# Access svn repository on windows from Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: windows, svn, ubuntu, subclipse

I am new to Linux and I am trying to setup eclipse with subclipse plugin to access my svn repository which is hosted on a Windows server.  Everything is installed fine.  When I try to create a new repository location, I am not sure how to identify the location in sublipse.  I have successfully mounted the windows share and I can browse the files from the File browser but I am not sure what to type in the location url.  On windows I used to type file:///p:/nameOfRepository

Thanks!

Comment: I've never seen addressing svn repositories by their folder. I always thought that a web server(like apache) is needed.

Comment: @kubal5003 Subversion supports multiple protocols: local filesystem (`file://`), svnserve (`svn://`), Authenticated svnserve via SSH (`ssh+svn://`), WebDAV (`http://`), WebDAV over SSL (`https://`)...

Answer (score 2):

subversion **does** support local access via the `file:///` access scheme (see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion_%28software%29#Repository_access)). on linux, your location should thus be along the lines of `file:///your_mount_point/nameOfRepository`

EDIT: maybe first try to access your repository from the command line (to keep subclipse out of the game until you've figured out the correct path). in early versions, subclipse could only connect to a local repository when used with the JavaHL library, not the JavaSVN library -- don't know whether this is still the case though...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that is exactly my problem since I am new to linux, I am not sure what would be "my_mount_point".  In File Browser I just see "e$ on WindowsServerName".  I tried putting that after file:/// but it did not work

Comment: running "mount -v" from the command line should give you a list of all mounted file systems...

Comment: mount -v does not show anything related to the windows share.  I am not sure if this is related to me creating the mount using the gui, Places->Conntect to server...

Comment: hmmm... this sounds very ubuntu-specific. maybe you should isolate/re-phrase the mounting aspect of this question and post it over at serverfault.com